# How to save key in localStorage to be retrieve later when you go back to your page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

- I have a page, and I want to save the key to be retrieved later. This key is use to determine the last selected active item in the carousel. What do I need to do using localStorage in ReactJS?

```
    import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react'
    import { truncateString } from '@helpers'
    import './styles.css'
    class RoutineSidebar extends Component {
        handleOnClick = key => {
            const { currentSlideKey } = this.props;
            const isExerciseDone = this.props.skipExerciseValidation(currentSlideKey);

            if(isExerciseDone || key < this.props.currentSlideKey) {
                if(this.props.skipExerciseValidation(key === 0 ? 0 : key - 1)) {
                    this.props.setKey(key);
                }
            } else {
                if(key === this.props.currentSlideKey + 1) {
                    this.props.openSkipExerModal(); 
                }
            }
            React.useEffect(() => {
                localStorage.setItem('selectedRoutine', key);
             }, [key]);
        }

        checkExerciseStatusSkipped = key => {
            const { routineList } = this.props;

            return routineList[key].skipped;
        };

        checkExerciseStatusDone = key => {
            const { routineList } = this.props;

            return routineList[key].done;
        }

        checkExercisesSelected = key => {
            const { routineList } = this.props;


            return routineList[key];
        }

        render() {
            const { exercises, currentSlideKey } = this.props;
            const todaysRoutineThumbnails = exercises.map((exercise, key) => {
                return (
                    <div key={key} onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(key)} className={key === currentSlideKey ? 'thumbnail-container selected-exercise' : 'thumbnail-container'}>
                        <div className="row todays-routine">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                {
                                    this.checkExerciseStatusSkipped(key) ? <Fragment><i className="fas fa-times-circle status-indicator-warning" />
                                        <div className="scThumb">
                                            <img className='active-thumbnail img-opaque' alt="todays-routine-thumbnail" src={exercise.thumbnail} />
                                        </div>
                                    </Fragment>
                                        : this.checkExerciseStatusDone(key) ? <Fragment><i className="fas fa-check-circle status-indicator-done" />
                                        <div className="scThumb">
                                            <img className='active-thumbnail img-opaque' alt="todays-routine-thumbnail" src={exercise.thumbnail} />
                                        </div>
                                    </Fragment>
                                        : !this.checkExerciseStatusDone(key) && !this.checkExerciseStatusSkipped(key) && <Fragment><div className="routine-exercise-counter">{key + 1}</div><div className="scThumb">
                                            <img className='active-thumbnail' alt="todays-routine-thumbnail" src={exercise.thumbnail} />
                                        </div>
                                    </Fragment>    
                                }                            
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">    
                                <div className="thumbnail-info clearfix">
                                    <p className="thumbnail-title">{truncateString(exercise.exerciseName, 30)}</p>
                                    <p className="thumbnail-description">This is the best exercise for back pain ever made</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                )
            })

            return (
                <div className="todays-routine-container">
                    <h1>{this.props.header}</h1>                
                    {todaysRoutineThumbnails} 
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default RoutineSidebar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use **useEffect** hook inside a class-based component.

to use localStorage with React you don't need anything, just use it directly.

I guess if you replaced your useEffect code with this code, it will work fine.

```
setTimeout(() => {
      window.localStorage.setItem("selectedRoutine", key);
    }, 0);
```

Comment: Is there a chance I can save the selectedRoutine and use it after even though I'm logged in/logged out on my dashboard? In that instance the localstorage should be gone, right?  I was thinking of using redux to save the state in the store. Any directions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is a difference between localStorage and sessionStorage, 
**localStorage**: the data is persistent so you can use it for what you are describing.
**sessionStorage**: data is cleared once you close the tab.

check this [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) for more info

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got a gist of it. What I'm after now is to save the clicked routine to firebase so that the clicked routine state is maintained upon navigating away/logging out and returning. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to create one util.js file for this kind of comman usages and paste below code and use these functions by just import.

```
export const getLocalStorage = (key) => {
    const localStorageData = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (localStorageData) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorageData);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

export const setLocalStorage = (key, value) => {
    if (key && value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react'
    import { truncateString } from '@helpers'
    import './styles.css'
    class RoutineSidebar extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.setState={
                activeCarouselItem: ""
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            this.setState({
                activeCarouselItem: localStorage.getItem('selectedRoutine')?localStorage.getItem('selectedRoutine'): ""
            })
        }

        handleOnClick = key => {
            const { currentSlideKey } = this.props;
            const isExerciseDone = this.props.skipExerciseValidation(currentSlideKey);

            if(isExerciseDone || key < this.props.currentSlideKey) {
                if(this.props.skipExerciseValidation(key === 0 ? 0 : key - 1)) {
                    this.props.setKey(key);
                }
            } else {
                if(key === this.props.currentSlideKey + 1) {
                    this.props.openSkipExerModal(); 
                }
            }
            // React.useEffect(() => {
                // localStorage.setItem('selectedRoutine', key);
             // }, [key]);
             this.setState({activeCarouselItem: key })

        }

        checkExerciseStatusSkipped = key => {
            const { routineList } = this.props;

            return routineList[key].skipped;
        };

        checkExerciseStatusDone = key => {
            const { routineList } = this.props;

            return routineList[key].done;
        }

        checkExercisesSelected = key => {
            const { routineList } = this.props;


            return routineList[key];
        }

        render() {
            const { exercises, currentSlideKey } = this.props;
            const todaysRoutineThumbnails = exercises.map((exercise, key) => {
                return (
                    <div key={key} onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(key)} className={key === currentSlideKey ? 'thumbnail-container selected-exercise' : 'thumbnail-container'}>
                        <div className="row todays-routine">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                {
                                    this.checkExerciseStatusSkipped(key) ? <Fragment><i className="fas fa-times-circle status-indicator-warning" />
                                        <div className="scThumb">
                                            <img className='active-thumbnail img-opaque' alt="todays-routine-thumbnail" src={exercise.thumbnail} />
                                        </div>
                                    </Fragment>
                                        : this.checkExerciseStatusDone(key) ? <Fragment><i className="fas fa-check-circle status-indicator-done" />
                                        <div className="scThumb">
                                            <img className='active-thumbnail img-opaque' alt="todays-routine-thumbnail" src={exercise.thumbnail} />
                                        </div>
                                    </Fragment>
                                        : !this.checkExerciseStatusDone(key) && !this.checkExerciseStatusSkipped(key) && <Fragment><div className="routine-exercise-counter">{key + 1}</div><div className="scThumb">
                                            <img className='active-thumbnail' alt="todays-routine-thumbnail" src={exercise.thumbnail} />
                                        </div>
                                    </Fragment>    
                                }                            
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">    
                                <div className="thumbnail-info clearfix">
                                    <p className="thumbnail-title">{truncateString(exercise.exerciseName, 30)}</p>
                                    <p className="thumbnail-description">This is the best exercise for back pain ever made</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                )
            })

            return (
                <div className="todays-routine-container">
                    <h1>{this.props.header}</h1>                
                    {todaysRoutineThumbnails} 
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default RoutineSidebar
```